# Access variables from another file in Lua

Tags: lua

I have this little problem...

I have 2 files, each being in a different directory.
The first file haves an integer called xp, storing the amount of xp the player haves, and I need to know how to access that variable in another file.

So here is my question: How can I use all the variables from the first file, in another file that is in another directory?

Please don't come with too complicated answers, because I'm not that good in Lua. :)

Comment: Is this "first file" a file on disk or a running script?

Comment: It is one directory back, and into another folder. And both of the scripts is running on the same time.

Comment: So this isn't "load a variable from a file" then this is "talk to another running script for a variable it has in memory"?

Comment: Then that's entirely up to your scripts.

Comment: I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: You need to write your scripts such that they can be queried from the outside. How you do that is up to you. They could listen on a socket, they could listen on a fifo, they could listen for signals and dump information to a specific location, etc. You have to processes that need to communicate. You need to design a communication channel. This isn't a "lua" question in any real way. If these scripts are part of the same application then they should both be running by the same application instance and may have a built-in communication channel. If not back to the previous comments.

Comment: I just mean, how to include the variables. I remember someone told me about include or import or something like that. But I'm not really sure.

Comment: You can `dofile` or `require` another file *from disk* but that doesn't help if the variable contents you are looking for are *in memory* of some other running process.

Comment: "both of the scripts is running on the same time": Do you mean that you are running two programs (processes) or just that you have run one script and then another script into one program? Please [edit] to show the commands and those parts of your code.

Comment: @TomBlodget - Probably, OP is talking about Lua scripts runnable from one host application using the same Lua VM instance (usual situation for client-side game scripting).